# Value is null from change event on dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-5

Having a `changeEvent` on the `DropDownListFor`, it does trigger the code for the event, however the selected item is null, i.e. `$(this).val();` is `null`

**View:**

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#selected_listBulletinBoardsMessages").change(function (e) {
            var val = $(this).val();          
            ..
        });
    });
</script>
<div>

    <div id="selected_listBulletinBoardsMessages">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.listBulletinBoardsMessages, Model.listBulletinBoardsMessages.Select(b => new SelectListItem() { Value = b.Department, Text = b.Department }), "All Departments", new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>


</div>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `div` elements don't have "values".  You want the value of the `select` element.  Ideally you'd bind to *that* element's `change` event instead:

```
$("#selected_listBulletinBoardsMessages select").change(function (e) {
    var val = $(this).val();          
    ..
});
```

But if, for reasons outside the context of this question, you want to bind to the `div` like you currently are then you can get the value from the `select` inside of it.  The `e` event variable that you already have can get you there.  Perhaps something like this:

```
$("#selected_listBulletinBoardsMessages").change(function (e) {
    var val = $(e.target).val();          
    ..
});
```

Naturally, this would likely need to change if you have more than one `select` element inside the `div`.  Currently that's not the case in the code you're showing, though.

Note also that this is based on the assumption that `DropDownListFor()` is indeed generating a `select` element.  I can't imagine why it wouldn't, but I suppose it's possible.  What you're at least going to want to do is examine the actual HTML and see what's there in order to refine any JavaScript code used to access that HTML.

Comment: For the second case, `$(e.target).val()` would be more appropriate

Comment: @A.Wolff: True, completely slipped my mind.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`div` doesn't have the `change` event.

You should listen for `change` event of `select`, thus specify the ID to `DropDownListFor` element.

```
<div>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.listBulletinBoardsMessages, 
      Model.listBulletinBoardsMessages.Select(b => new SelectListItem() { Value = b.Department, Text = b.Department }),
     "All Departments", 
     new { @class = "form-control", 
           id="selected_listBulletinBoardsMessages" 
     })
</div>
```

Comment: *"div doesn't have the change event"* - Technically true, though such an event can certainly be caught and handled on a `div` through event propagation.  The original code *handles* the event just fine, the value simply isn't on that element.

Comment: @David, I overlooked propagation

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#selected_listBulletinBoardsMessages select").change(function (e) {
        var val = $(this).val();          
        ..
    });
});
</script>
```

because you are trying to call `div` `change event` which should not be there in this case.